# C# MS Chart Control - highlight today's date in Gantt Chart

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, gantt-chart

The title of this question says it all.

I've got a gantt chart (RangeBar) made using the MS Chart Control, and at present I have some StripLines to highlight weekends and the start of each month, but I need one to appear on today's date only so the user can see where we are at the mo.

Is this possible with this control, or am I fishing for unicorns?

If it's possible, how?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out:

```
StripLine strpToday = new StripLine();
        strpToday.IntervalOffset = DateTime.Today.ToOADate();
        strpToday.StripWidth = 1;
        strpToday.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
        chtHC.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(strpToday);
```